# how would you generate fake account numbers for a company project with SQL?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a big data set in Redshift which my company will share with university students to analyze. I need to mask the real customer account numbers.

I've looked at the random function but there's one catch: some customers are repeated, so I need to retain that for the analysis to be useful. Also, with a random number there's a small possibility you would repeat account numbers, right?

How would you achieve this? Generate a new_random_id. It must be unique from all others in the table (there are over 4 million in the table), but must be the same for those rows where the actual account ID is the same.

```
+-------------------+---------------+---------+
| actual_accound_id | new_random_id | status  |
+-------------------+---------------+---------+
|               100 |           123 | new     |
|               100 |           123 | upgrade |
|               200 |           249 | new     |
|               300 |           401 | upgrade |
+-------------------+---------------+---------+
```

I realize I could first generate a mapping table like this below, and then join to the main table, but it still doesn't solve the problem of possibly repeating new random IDs.

```
select distinct actual_account_id, cast(random()*1000000 as int) as new_random_id
into mapping_table
from t1;
```

Comment: Have you investigated the hashing functions on Redshift? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/hash-functions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a mapping table using window functions:

```
select actual_account_id,
       row_number() over (order by random()) as fake_account_id
from t1
group by actual_account_id;
```

This should be a meaningless sequential number.

Redshift might be a bit slow on the `ROW_NUMBER()` with no `PARTITION BY`.  If performance is an issue, you can use something like this:

```
select actual_account_id,
       count(*) * 100 + row_number(partition by tmp order by random()) as fake_acocunt_number
from (select actual_account_id,
             cast(random()*1000000 as int) as tmp
      from t1
      group by actual_account_id
     ) t;
```